# using ajax show open new window

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

in this code there is some error related to the link and it is not opening the page .there error may be in the link that i am giving and it is not showing the alert in which it will have the data of the other page .in my pc the link of the file is "D:\xampp\htdocs\cart\welcome.php" means its in folder "D:\xampp\htdocs\cart" now what i change to make it right and i am using this on my pc with xampp not making webstie

```html
 <html>
<head>
<script>  
  function check(form) {
  if (form.email.value == "id@gmail.com") {
    document.getElementById("displayu").innerHTML ="correct username".fontcolor("green");
  } else if (form.email.value == "") {
    document.getElementById("displayu").innerHTML ="<font color='red'>blank username</font>";
  } else if (form.email.value != "") {
    var email = document.getElementById('email');
    var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

    if (!filter.test(email.value)) {
      document.getElementById("displayu").innerHTML ="Please provide a valid email address";

    }
       else {document.getElementById("displayu").innerHTML ="wrong email";} 
 } 

  if (form.pswrd.value == "123") {
    document.getElementById("displayp").innerHTML ="correct password";
  } else if (form.pswrd.value == "") {
    document.getElementById("displayp").innerHTML ="<span style='color:red'>blank password</span>";
  }
 else {document.getElementById("displayp").innerHTML ="wrong password";} 
  makeRequest('http://D:/xampp/htdocs/cart/welcome.php');
    }


  function makeRequest(url) {
    httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

    if (!httpRequest) {
      alert('Giving up :( Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance');
      return false;
    }
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = alertContents;
    httpRequest.open('GET', url);
    httpRequest.send();
  }

  function alertContents() {
    if (httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
        alert(httpRequest.responseText);
  document.open();
        document.write(httpRequest.responseText);
        document.close();
        
      } else {
        alert('There was a problem with the request.');
      }
    }
  }
</script>  
</head>
<body>
<h1>for login</h1>
<h3>email=id@gmail.com   and password=123</h3>
<form name="login">
<div id="displayu"></div>
<div id="displayp"></div>
  Username <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
  Password <input type="password" name="pswrd"/>
  <input type="button" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Login" />

  <input type="reset" value="reset"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `http://D:/xampp/htdocs/cart/welcome.php` isn't a valid URL.  Web servers and file systems are two very different things.

Comment: `'http://D:/xampp/htdocs/cart/welcome.php'` change this to `'file:///D:/xampp/htdocs/cart/welcome.php'`.. But why you need to provide `full path` or `absolute path`, It's best practice to provide the `relative link`.

Comment: Create the fiddler for it, so it is easy for another to trace your bug.

Comment: what error? why you are using invalid link?

Comment: its still not opening

Comment: @SaurabhSharma: "Still not opening" - Well, what did you change?  If you followed Kalpesh's first suggestion, that won't fix anything.  Because a file system isn't a web server.  Refer to the answer below.

Comment: yeah i followed kalpesh

Comment: @SaurabhSharma: Well, Kalpesh was incorrect.  Quentin's answer below is correct.  You need to host your PHP page on a web server and use a valid HTTP URL to access it via AJAX.  That URL can be your localhost, it doesn't have to be an external server somewhere.  But it does have to be a web server in order for PHP or AJAX to work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to run a webserver and then request your resource from that using a network name (e.g. `http://localhost/cart/welcome.php`).

A URL to a local filepath would start with `file:` instead of `http:`, but most implementations of XMLHttpRequest would refuse to support it, and it wouldn't cause the PHP to be executed (since PHP, in this context, is a *server* side programming language).

Comment: "There was a problem with the request." basically its in the code as an alert

Comment: @SaurabhSharma — That's an error message **you** wrote. It means that the request completed without getting a 200 OK response. What response did it get? Do some basic debugging. Look in the Developer Tools built in to your browser. Look at the Network tab. Look at the Console.

Comment: i am new i dont know all this :(