# lnk with database with ajax in html

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

The code is showing this error ,dont know how to make it right

> "GET http://d/xampp/htdocs/cart/getuser.php net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED  showUser @showuser.php:27  onclick @showuser.php:9".

Even though in my computer the location of file is "http://d/xampp/htdocs/cart/getuser.php" . I am using xampp

```js
function showUser() {
  httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

  if (!httpRequest) {
    alert('Giving up :( Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance');
    return false;
  }
  httpRequest.onreadystatechange = alertContents;
  httpRequest.open("GET", "http://D:/xampp/htdocs/cart/getuser.php", true);
  httpRequest.send();
}

function alertContents() {
  if (httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
    if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }


}
```

```html
<form>
  enter digit : <input type='text' id='id' /> <br />
  <input type='button' onclick='showUser(this.value)' value='select' />



</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>
```

Comment: why are you calling the php file using a local url? is D: you xampp install drive ? you should calling http://localhost or similar vhost url

Comment: Change your URL to `localhost/cart/getuser.php`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using ajax show open new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38010950/using-ajax-show-open-new-window)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URL is not valid.

```
http://D:/xampp/htdocs/cart/getuser.php
```

The D:/ is not valid. You can't use : in a URL. And you can't just directly reference a file on disk either - you reference a URL, which is not the same thing at all.

Does changing it to

```
http:/localhost/d/xampp/htdocs/cart/getuser.php
```

work? You've suggested something like this might be the right link. You need to check that your webserver is running and actually serving content at this link.